# How to implement search bar using textWatcher in my application?

Tags: java, android, search, textwatcher

In my **android project**, My editText should suggest names from the database while typing, containing each letter. What Iv'e searched so far is using **TextChangedListener (TextWatcher).** This seems to be simple but how can I check if the input is equals to the data in cursor by every letter?

**These are my codes:**

```
    b4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
           Cursor a = db.getAllregisteredusers();


        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });
```

**Query:**

```
public Cursor getAllregisteredusers (){
    SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT tableinfo.*, tableacc.*" +
            "FROM tableinfo JOIN tableacc ON tableinfo.userid = tableacc.userid WHERE tableacc.userstatus=? ";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(selectQuery , new String[]{ "REGISTERED"});


    return data;
}
```

Ive tried searching already but I cant seem to get it.  How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a [Search Interface](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) for this. The hardest part is usually creating a database and it sounds like you already have one. There should be plenty of github examples on creating Search Interfaces.